# date_create function is not working in php

Tags: php

I have an issue.I need to calculate the time difference but here the `date_create` function is not showing any output in php.I am explaining my code below.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($orderqry)){
    $exit_date=$row['delivered_datetime'];
    if($exit_date!=='0000-00-00 00:00:00'){  
       $deldate=date_create($exit_date);
       $today=date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
      echo $today;exit;
      $interval = date_diff($deldate, $today);
      $hours = $interval->format('%h');    
}
}
```

Here i am trying to echo `$today` but its not giving any result.Here i need to calculate the time difference in hour.In my DB i have existing time in the format of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.Please help me.

Comment: _"Returns new DateTime object."_  You'll need to format it to display or compare.

Comment: date_create return an instance of DateTime not a string, you have to use `$today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` if you want to echo the result

Comment: `echo $today` cause an error. `echo $hours;` it's ok. Please note that `%h` doesn't return total hours, it return only values 0-23. To obtain total value you have to write `$hours = $interval->h + ($interval->days*24);`

Comment: Calling `date_create()` without parameter is same as creating `DateTime` with current date time. So `$today=date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));` will have same output as `$today=date_create();`

Answer (score 1):

`$today` is [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instance. To echo it you need to call its `format()` method.

```
echo $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: How can i extract the time interval.

Comment: You have done it `$hours = $interval->format('%h');`

Comment: i am trying to echo `$hours` but its not coming.

Comment: Are you sure? `echo $hours;` should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

[date_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) is an alias of: [DateTime::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). see below example, I have assigned 6 Hour ago date in `$exit_date`. so ideally difference from current date should be 6 Hour.

```
$exit_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-6 Hours'));
$deldate=date_create($exit_date); //returns datetime class object
$today=date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$interval = date_diff($deldate, $today);
echo $hours = $interval->format('%h'); // output 6 hours
```

If you want to print date from `$today` variable then use:

```
echo $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //output: today's date in Y-m-d H:i:s format
```

for more detail have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php